# How to duplicate rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
create table Contacts (key1 int, Accn varchar (20))
INSERT INTO Contacts 
select 1234,'ABCD' UNION
select 1234,'EFG' UNION
select 1234,'GAB' UNION
select 1234,'PBC' UNION
select 89023,'MONQ'  
   

CREATE TABLE SCANDOCS (Accn varchar (20), FileDesc varchar (50),BReg  varchar (50))
select 'ABCD','100_MP','813' union
select 'ABCD','200_KA','843' union
select 'EFG','100_MP','3209' union
select 'GAB','800_JLZG','2357' union
select 'MONQ','700_NMO','94266'
```

I need to find Key1 and check that its accn  in Scandocs in the column filedesc has either the values '100_MP' or '200_KA'. In the example it exists for `Key1 =1234` and `ACCN=ABCD,EFG`. Once I find it for a specific key I need to insert a row into Scandocs for all the other accn under that key that don't have these filedesc.

Also, if an accn under a key has one of these values but with a different BReg then another acc under the same key with same fildesc I need to also insert that row into the scandocs with the accn that doesn't have that same filedesc and Breg.

The outcome should be

```
accn      | filedesc  | Breg
ABCD      | 100_MP    |813
ABCD      | 200_KA    |843
ABCD      | 100_MP    |3209
EFG       | 100_MP    |813
EFG       | 100_MP    |3209
EFG       | 200_KA    |843
GAB       |800_JLZG   |2357
GAB       | 100_MP    |813
GAB       | 200_KA    |843
GAB       | 100_MP    |3209
MONQ      |700_NMO    |94266
```

MONQ acc is under key1=89023 and no acc under that key1 has filedesc with values 100_mp or 200_KA
so we don't need to copy rows with 100 or 200 since they don't exist for that key1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate all that should be there.
Then you can compare that with what's already there.

The solution here inserts all from CTE_ALL_ACC_FD that doesn't match with what's already in SCANDOCS.

> ```
> WITH CTE_ACCOUNTS AS (
>   SELECT c.accn, c.key1
>   FROM Contacts c
>   INNER JOIN SCANDOCS d 
>     ON d.accn = c.accn
>   WHERE c.key1 = 1234
>   GROUP BY c.accn, c.key1
> )
> , CTE_FILEDESCS AS
> (
>   SELECT DISTINCT filedesc, breg
>   FROM SCANDOCS
>   WHERE accn IN (select accn from CTE_ACCOUNTS)
>     AND filedesc IN ('100_MP','200_KA')
> )
> , CTE_ALL_ACC_FD AS (
>   SELECT DISTINCT accn, filedesc, breg
>   FROM CTE_ACCOUNTS a
>   CROSS JOIN CTE_FILEDESCS fd
> )
> INSERT INTO SCANDOCS (
>  accn, 
>  filedesc, 
>  breg
> )
> SELECT 
>  afd.accn, 
>  afd.filedesc, 
>  afd.breg
> FROM CTE_ALL_ACC_FD afd
> LEFT JOIN SCANDOCS sdoc 
>   ON sdoc.accn = afd.accn
>  AND sdoc.filedesc = afd.filedesc
>  AND sdoc.breg = afd.breg
> WHERE sdoc.filedesc IS NULL;
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM SCANDOCS
> ORDER BY accn, filedesc
> ```
>
> ```
> accn | filedesc | breg 
> :--- | :------- | :----
> ABCD | 100_MP   | 3209 
> ABCD | 100_MP   | 813  
> ABCD | 200_KA   | 843  
> EFG  | 100_MP   | 3209 
> EFG  | 100_MP   | 813  
> EFG  | 200_KA   | 843  
> GAB  | 100_MP   | 3209 
> GAB  | 100_MP   | 813  
> GAB  | 200_KA   | 843  
> GAB  | 800_JLZG | 2357 
> MONQ | 700_NMO  | 94266
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e0aa99f12a2a98aa80ff6f36a3e9d5ec)*

Comment: @lola I guess you can accept your first solution then.